# Get all posts related to a specific taxonomy in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, function, custom-taxonomy

[image]
I have created Custom Post Type "Music" and artists taxonomy related to it, I used the below code to list all artists but I what I want is, If any artist was clicked a list of his songs should be shown only.

```
<?php $terms = get_terms([
    'taxonomy' => 'artists',
]);

if (!empty($terms)) {
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        echo $term->name;
        echo "<br><br>";
    }
}
?>
```

Any one knows how can I display the songs for a specific artist on click?

In other words, how to get the id of the clicked element in order to iterate over the taxonomy and get the specified element?

As far as I am concerned, the elements found inside a taxonomy don't have an id?

Example: The user clicked on Roddy Rich, How to iterate over the taxonomy and get that element?

Comment: _"As far as I am concerned, the elements found inside a taxonomy don't have an id?"_ - of course they do.

Comment: They are listed as text inside <p> so they don't have an id

Comment: Just because you created output that doesn't contain any ID, doesn't mean that the actual data behind this doesn't have any. So fix your _output_ then. Instead of just writing text without any structure into a paragraph - create individual HTML elements then. And put the ID value onto/into that in _some_ form, however you need it for your further processing.

Comment: WordPress already provides templates for term archive pages, that will list all the posts. You can use https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_link/ to create a link to that page, for a specific term.

Comment: I'll try it, what I want that if I click for example on Ariana Grande it must show me all songs related to her.